# NodeJs Swagger Typescript controller not found

Tags: node.js, api, typescript, swagger

nodejs application that i'm developing i'm using swagger and typescript on my controller it looks like

```
const q_mapping = require('../../config/q_mapping');
import { amqpMessenger } from '../tools/amqp';

const survey = {
  surveyServiceCheck : (req,res) =>{
       amqpMessenger({serviceCheck : true},res, q_mapping.survey);
  }
}

export {survey}
```

and swagger complain about

> Cannot resolve the configured swagger-router handler:
>   survey_surveyServiceCheck

when i see the generated js file it export something like that

```
"use strict";
var q_mapping = require('../../config/q_mapping');
var amqp_1 = require("../tools/amqp");
var survey = (function () {
    function survey() {
    }
    survey.prototype.surveyServiceCheck = function (req, res) {
        amqp_1.amqpMessenger({ serviceCheck: true }, res, q_mapping.survey);
    };
    return survey;
}());
exports.survey = survey;
```

and when i menually change to `exports.survey = survey;` line in to `module.exports = survey;` swagger hits the controller.

what do i need to change on my typescript to generate above out put or did i do something wrong when i write controller?
 my swagger definition like

```
/survey:
    # binds a127 app logic to a route
    x-swagger-router-controller: survey
    get:
      description:  Check whether the survey service is up or not
      # used as the method name of the controller
      operationId: surveyServiceCheck
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Success
          schema:
            # a pointer to a definition
            $ref: "#/definitions/defaultResponse"
        # responses may fall through to errors
        default:
          description: Error
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I suppose that `survey` is not a `const` but a `class`. Otherwise, the TypeScript compiler wouldn't create a function object as value for `survey`. Apart from that, you should use `export =` ([documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require))

```
const q_mapping = require('../../config/q_mapping');
import { amqpMessenger } from '../tools/amqp';

class survey {
  surveyServiceCheck(req,res) {
    amqpMessenger({serviceCheck : true},res, q_mapping.survey);
  }
}

export = survey
```

Generated JavaScript file looks like this:

```
"use strict";
var q_mapping = require('../../config/q_mapping');
var amqp_1 = require("../tools/amqp");
var survey = (function () {
    function survey() {
    }
    survey.prototype.surveyServiceCheck = function (req, res) {
        amqp_1.amqpMessenger({ serviceCheck: true }, res, q_mapping.survey);
    };
    return survey;
}());
module.exports = survey;
```

This is equivalent to the generated file you postet including the fix you had to do manually.